# How to return to beginning of while loop java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

How to break out of forloop and return to beginning of while loop. My function should return 111221 when I input 1211 since there is one 1, one 2, and two 1's. If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

```
public static String occurence(String input) {

    int s = 0;
    String out = "";

    int count = 0;

    while(s < input.length()) {

        int num = getInt(input, s);

        for(int r = s; r < input.length(); r++) {

            if(num == getInt(input, r)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(count);

                out += count;
                out += num;
                s += count;
                count = 0;

                // Jump to start of while loop
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: what is your getInt method and what it returning? please provide full code.

Comment: Or just use Break Statement for the exit from the Loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use the break statement

```
 public static String occurence(String input){

int s = 0;
String out = "";

int count = 0;


while(s<input.length()){


    //System.out.println(s);

    int num = getInt(input, s);

    for(int r = s; r<input.length(); r++){


        if(num == getInt(input, r)){

            count++;


        }else{

            System.out.println(count);

            out+=count;
            out+=num;
            s+=count;
            count = 0;

            break;



        }

    }

}

return out;


}
```